# What is StreamSpecification property of AWS DynamoD Table used for?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am playing around with DynamoDb. I am not sure what is the purpose of StreamSpecification and why we should or shouldn't use it? I have read the documentation [Aws - StreamSpecification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-streamspecification.html) but it does not explain much as what it does.

```
MovieTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "Name"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "Genre"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - AttributeName: "Rating"
          AttributeType: "N"
        - AttributeName: "DateReleased"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: "Name"
        KeyType: "HASH"
      - AttributeName: "Genre"
        KeyType: "RANGE"
      - AttributeName: "Rating"
        KeyType: "RANGE"
      - AttributeName: "DateReleased"
        KeyType: "RANGE"
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: ExpireAfter
        Enabled: false
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StreamSpecification` allows you to enable the optional **DynamoDB Streams** support for this table. DynamoDB Streams allow you to read all the changes to a table as a **stream** - which you can use for various reasons such as replicating the same changes to another table, checking for suspicious activity, and so on. You can read an introduction to the DynamoDB Streams feature [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html).

If you don't want to enable a stream on your table (and since you didn't know what this was, you probably don't :-)), you can just ignore `StreamSpecification`.